# What is the command for running the test with mocha expressjs

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

My test file,

```
describe('a basic test',function(){
    it('it should pass when everything is okay',function(){
        console.log('hi')
    })
})
```

My test result with the command 'mocha'

```
hi
․

  1 passing (9ms)
```

But how can i get results like below,

```
a basic test
it should pass when everything is okay
 hi
```

With tick mark as success,can any one help me.

Answer (score 1):

The default reporter for Mocha is `spec`, which outputs the report like you want:

```
  a basic test
hi
    ✓ it should pass when everything is okay


  1 passing (6ms)
```

So the question is why Mocha isn't using the default reporter in your case (instead, it's using `dot`). The most likely reason for that is that you have a file called `./test/mocha.opts` that contains this line:

```
--reporter dot
```

If you don't want `dot` as the default, just remove the line. If you want `dot` to be the default, but occasionally want to override it, pass another reporter on the command line:

```
mocha --reporter spec
# or shorter:
mocha -R spec
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can i test each function in my routes

Comment: @nlr_p I can only globally point you towards modules like [`supertest`](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) which you can use for that. But it ultimately depends on what you want to test, and how you code is implemented.

Comment: i have a folder that contains all my routes,will calling those files performs testing?

Comment: @nlr_p no, you need to declare test cases for each route.

Comment: for that am i need to install anything else like chai?

Comment: @nlr_p `chai` is useful, also the aforementioned `supertest` is useful.